# An HTTP POST redirect to HTTPS leads to a data lose?

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, post

Faced with an issue when a POST request redirected has no Content-Length.

First got this issue with AWS ALB and its 301 for HTTP => HTTPS redirect, and thought it was something with ALB itself.

Then configured just a common NGINX with HTTP 80 server and HTTP 443 server:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    ...

    location / {
        return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {

    listen       443 ssl;
...
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;        

        proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

And on the upstream, I have a simple Python web-server listening to the 8081 port.

Then, if run a request directly to the 443 port - all work well.
When I issue a request to the port  HTTP 80, which causes 302 redirect - the Python app says:

> ````
>     content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a
> bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' ```
> ````

I.e. `self.headers['Content-Length']` == `NoneType`.

While `curl` shows me data:

```
$ curl -vL -X POST http://example.com/ -d "param1=value1&param2=value2"
...
< HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
...
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 173
```

I'm not sure if this is NGINX-related issue at all (again - originally faced on AWS Application Load Balancer), but anyway...

Comment: Found solution, will add it here after full testing.

Answer (score 0):

In short: the solution was to use the 307 code redirect to avoid changing a requests' type from the `POST` to `GET`.

The related RFC doc is [here](https://rtfm.co.ua/goto/https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3).
The helpful Mozilla's [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302).
And long-read about this "detective" is [here](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/http-redirects-post-and-get-requests-and-lost-data/).